# Decoding Unknown Data Type

Tags: decode

I have received some encoded data from Arduino via PySerial. I have access to an application which decodes the data, but I need to know what it is doing and I do not have access to the source code.

Data file contents:

```
%N|nkNsnrNlnzNqnEOknJOlM
%VA@_@@hpZzbdIvzegvxefvkeavdeXvXeXvPeMvReDvlM
%PaA@gH@lnMO@QaLN@mbzM@cbmM@^beM@Pb_M@Fb]M@xaUM@balM
%Ma@@HI@FzJP@auPO@~uPO@{uPO@}uMO@vuN@wuyN@uuqN@xulM
%knOOinSOXnMOAnFOcmxNYmlNBm_NslSNqlHNclnM^N
%PezuReouLeluDeju~diuFe`uBeXuAeUu~dJuxdAu^N
%MM@NaJM@`MM@t`VM@h`aM@f`fM@Y`jM@O`mM@G`uM@{_BN@u_^N
%rN@tuhN@nu[N@kuRN@huEN@au{M@[uqM@Nu^M@CuFM@ttuL@at^N
%XlPMMlvLMlWLPlBLVllKMlWKDlCKKlrJNl[J`lHJPO
%pd|trdrttdjtudbtmd_tkd[tkdWtmdOtldGtvdHtPO
```

Output from application:

```
86 31 -48 97 -51 33 -1109 -3121 
-984 -358 551 -1108 584 -378 -1111 -3117 
-1758 -631 973 -1967 1034 -671 -1128 -3123 
-1670 -601 908 -1875 976 -642 -1151 -3130 
-1672 -602 890 -1885 976 -645 -1181 -3144 
-1685 -607 877 -1890 976 -643 -1191 -3156 
-1692 -616 869 -1904 973 -650 -1214 -3169 
-1704 -616 863 -1914 959 -649 -1229 -3181 
-1712 -627 861 -1928 953 -651 -1231 -3192 
-1710 -636 853 -1950 945 -648 -1245 -3218 
-1712 -646 845 -1970 946 -652 -1256 -3248 
-1710 -657 842 -1985 936 -658 -1267 -3274 
-1716 -660 845 -1996 923 -661 -1267 -3305 
-1724 -662 854 -2008 914 -664 -1264 -3326 
-1730 -663 865 -2010 901 -671 -1258 -3348 
-1722 -672 870 -2023 891 -677 -1267 -3369 
-1726 -680 874 -2033 881 -690 -1276 -3389 
-1727 -683 877 -2041 862 -701 -1269 -3406 
-1730 -694 885 -2053 838 -716 -1266 -3429 
-1736 -703 898 -2059 821 -735 -1248 -3448
```

I have tried several encodings like ASCII, UTF-8, and UUEncoding but none have given me any tangible results.

Does anyone have an idea as to what this could be?

Thanks in advance,

Cheers

Comment: Is the excerpt the complete contents of the file, as far as you know? Also can you disclose what the application is, when you wrote: `I have access to an application which decodes the data`

Comment: @user454038 Yes, the excerpt is the entire file contents. All I know about the application is that it was written in MATLAB 2011a and compiled with the MATLAB Compiler. Other than that, all I know is that it came from the company we licensed it from. The application looks for the garbled file and prints blank output if it doesn't find it.

Comment: What are the file paths, for example file path of the encoded data file, and what is the path (which includes name) of the application used to decode this file? Did the company provide any documentation or official literature about the stated purpose of the decoder application?